# What was Louis's dark gift in Interview with The Vampire?

Tags: plot-explanation, interview-with-the-vampire

Lestat (Tom Cruise) mentioned that he can read minds and told Louis (Brad Pitt) that every vampire has a dark gift and the dark gift is different for all of them. But Louis's dark gift wasn't revealed in the movie. What was his dark gift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He meant that the *degree* of that power (and *when* it manifests) varies. From the [IMDb FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110148/faq#.2.1.14):

> When someone is given the Dark Gift, it means they have been transformed from human to vampire. **The Dark Gift IS vampirism. In the Ricean universe, all vampires are granted the same abilities: telekinesis, pyrokinesis, telepathy, and mesmerism, along with enhanced senses, strength, and immortality. What was unique to each person was the degree to which a fledgling would manifest each power immediately after being born to darkness.** For example, when the Dark Gift was bestowed upon Lestat, he quickly developed a high degree of telepathic ability, whereas Louis did not.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the last line; Lestat was turned by a very old Vampire and prior to the events in Interview he feed on the ORIGINAL vampire - which is what garnered him a lot of power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Louis's gift was his humanity, he retained his human soul - feelings emotions, and although very painful for him, empathy. Hardly a gift one might think. However, we often see that vampire characters become jaded with their unfeeling unchanging existence & inability to feel. So perhaps it was a gift.

Answer (score -1):

I think Loui's gift was revealed by Antonio Banderas' character because he mentions it when he goes to his room in the coven. Wanting answers and not wanting to kill humans. He never lost his humanity. That was his dark gift.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.